# Best practice way to implement contoller As using UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Have a small search app using AngularJS and Elasticsearch. Trying to convert my the app from using `$scope` to `controller As` syntax. I'm using UI Router for my routes/states. Been trying to use

```
controller: 'HomeCtrl',
controllerAs: 'home'
```

in my state declarations. And then `var vm = this;` in controller to bind to the scope.

I switched `ng-model="searchTerms"` on my search input to `ng-model="home.searchTerms"` and everywhere else bindings would be needed. None of it works?

Is it better to use `ng-controller="HomeCtrl as home"` in a parent div? Is that best practice? Will it work with UI Router?

**UPDATE**
I now have

```
var vm = this;
vm.searchTerms = searchTerms;
```

BUT it still does not work, I keep getting this error in Chrome console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: searchTerms is not defined(…)
```

**UPDATED CONTROLLER**

```
'use strict';

angular.module("searchApp.autocomplete", [])
  .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$sce', '$state', '$stateParams', 'searchService', function($sce, $state, $stateParams, searchService) {

    var vm = this;
    var searchTerms = searchTerms;
    vm.searchTerms = searchTerms;

      vm.noResults = false;
      vm.isSearching = false;

    vm.results = {
      searchTerms: null,
      documentCount: null,
      documents: [],
      queryTime : null,
      searchTermGrams: null,
      itemsPerPage: 10,
      maxResults: 100
    };

      //autocomplete
    vm.autocomplete = {
        suggestions: [],
        corrections: []
    };
    vm.showAutocomplete = false;
```

Comment: are you making `searchTerms` visible via `vm`?  for example, in the controller, do you have a statement such as `vm.searchTerms = searchTerms`?

Comment: @ankur sorry for the delay, had to step out for a bit, let me check my code

Comment: @ankur please see UPDATE above

Comment: Could you post your controller, please? If you've defined searchTerms after you assign it to the alias, it could throw that error.

Comment: @ankur please see CONTROLLER above

Comment: Where and what exactly is `searchTerms`?  If it's a `var` and defined after the `vm.searchTerms = searchTerms;`, it would show as undefined due to it not being defined until after it's called.  In this case, you should move its definition to before you assign it to `vm.searchTerms`.

Comment: @ankur ok, thank you, let me try this out and I'll report back there, thanks for your help!

Comment: @ankur please see UPDATED CONTROLLER, I added more of the controller code so its hopefully more clear as to what I am doing wrong, still getting same error

Comment: `searchTerms` is not being initialized.  I take it it's a string?  I am updating my answer to reflect this.  Also, do all of your objects need to be visible outside of your controller? If not, you can remove the `vm.`.

Comment: Just read the error message. `searchTerms` is undefined.

Comment: @ankur thanks and yes its a string, no they don't, I'll accept your answer as soon as you update, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`controller: 'HomeCtrl as home'` will work with ui-router.

EDIT:

You also need to define and initialize any objects/variables before or while assigning them to `vm`.  In your updated code, you have defined `searchTerms` but it is not initialized.  Please see the following for possible ways to rectify this assuming `searchTerms` is a string.

```
var searchTerms = '';

var vm = this;
vm.searchTerms = searchTerms;
```

or depending on your usage needs, you can only initialize if it is undefined:

```
var searchTerms = searchTerms || '';

var vm = this;
vm.searchTerms = searchTerms;
```

or if you don't need to have a separate internal variable, you can init `vm.searchTerms` directly (however in most cases I personally do not prefer this method):

```
var vm = this;
vm.searchTerms = '';
```

Regarding the rest of the posted code, you should generally expose to your view only what you need to access from there and keep the rest contained within your controller (or service/factory, etc.).

So far I have yet to come across a solid, singular set of best practices for angular, however a great place to start is John Papa's [Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide).

Comment: thank you, I used this project to learn Angular and its been an adventure to say the least!

Comment: Glad to be of assistance.  :)