# How can I bind the json object returned from database to the dropdownlist in the jsp page

Tags: angularjs

I am using Spring MVC, I am much familiar with jQuery, but right now we got the need to work with angularjs, The Question is I have got an angular js MVC structure in my IDE. i.e. controller and service. I am calling REST API from the controller through service and getting a list of object back as a result, now I want the list of Object to be bind with DropDown list in the JSP page. I tried many options but could not do it, Please help me. 
I am displaying code below

jsp Page code

here how I have bind controller

```
<div data-ng-controller="UserController as ctrl">
    <div class="form-group required">
        <label for="role" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Role</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">  
            <select class="form-control"  ng-model="selectedRole"
                ng-options="roleVo.roleName for roleVo in roleVoList">
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

user_controller(angularjs)

```
 'use strict';
    var App = angular.module('myApp',[]);    
    alert("user_controller");
    App.controller('UserController', ['$scope', 'UserService', 
            function($scope, UserService) {
              var self = this;     
              self.roleVo={
                      roleId:'',roleName:''
              };
              selfroleVoList=[];                     
          self.getAllRole= function(){
              alert("Hi");
              UserService.getAllRole()
                  .then(
                       function(d) {
                            self.roleVoList = d;
                       },
                        function(errResponse){
                            console.error('Error while fetching Roles');
                        }
                     );
          };          
          $scope.init = function () {
               alert("init");
               self.getAllRole();
               alert("after getAllRole");            
          }          
         $scope.init();//on Form Load
    }]);
user_service(angularjs)
var App = angular.module('myApp',[]);
 App.factory('UserService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){    
        return {            
            getAllRole: function() {
                return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/tasktrac/user/getAllRole')
                    .then(
                        function(response){
                            return response.data;
                        }, 
                        function(errResponse){
                            console.error('Error while fetching role list');
                            return $q.reject(errResponse);
                        }
                    );
            },
    }
    }]);
```

Comment: You're probably binding the controller using the `controllerAs` so try changing `ng-options="roleVo.roleName for roleVo in roleVoList"` to `ng-options="roleVo.roleName for roleVo in $ctrl.roleVoList"`

Comment: no thats not working..!!

Comment: OK, so can you include the `$routeProvider` part in your app, or the part in your view where you bind the controller? Also you wrote _"I tried many options but could not do it"_ - What is actually happen? Do don't see the list in your view?

Comment: I see, so if you using `data-ng-controller="UserController as ctrl"` then you need to reference the objects in the view with a `ctrl.` prefix (`ng-options="roleVo.roleName for roleVo in ctrl.roleVoList"`)

Comment: Also, take a look at this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631366/best-practice-way-to-implement-contoller-as-using-ui-router)

Comment: yeah that solved my problem but one new problem has arise, I am getting values in dropdown now but the first <option></option> is inserted by angularjs. which is blank, how can I get rid of that?

Comment: Did you changed `ng-model="selectedRole"` to `ng-model="ctrl.selectedRole"`? And you need to set in your controller a default value from the `roleVoList` array (`self.selectedRole = self.roleVoList[0]` (In the resolve function of the `UserService.getAllRole()`)

Comment: Thats not working...

Comment: No, wait! you're the one adding the empty option, take a look at the view, you have `<option value=""></option>`

Comment: So everything works now, or would there be anything else I can help with?